# Convergence of inner product of vector space of infinite sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I am trying to prove the convergence of the inner space in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$
Defined as
$$ \langle a | b \rangle := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}^{*}a_{k} $$
Considering that every sequence satisfy
$$||a||^{2}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^2 < \infty $$
Here is my attempt,
By cauchy schwarz inequality,
$$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}^{*} a_{k} \right|^{2} ≤ (  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| b_{k} ^{*} \right|^{2} ) (  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| a_{k}  \right|^{2}) $$
From the condition of the norm, there is a $M \in \mathbb{R} $ such that,
$$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{k}^{*} a_{k} \right| < M $$
It can be seen from the last argument that the series has a lower and upper bound.
I get stuck there as i can not find a way to prove convergence from the previous idea.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a hint.

Comment: You can have the intermediate sum of $\sum |b_k^*a_k|^2$...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_k$ and $b_k$ are positive, then by your analysis $\sum a_kb_k = \sum b_k^*a_k$ has an upper bound. The partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k$ is also monotonous, so the whole series must converges.

Now get back to the general situation. For $x=(a_k)$ and $y=(b_k)$, $\sum b_k^*a_k$ is absolutely convergent. (Or, you can pass from the Cauchy criterion of series). So it is convergent.

Comment: How do you conclude that the series $\sum b_{k} ^{*} a_{k}$ is absolutely convergent if the absolute value is outside the sum? Sorry if the question is trivial

Comment: @CristhianMartinez08 I meant that $\sum |a_k||b_k|$ is convergent by the previous paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your reasoning,  i understand it now, thanks for the help